How can I play locally recorded audio files with audioplayers?
I'm working on a project where the items contain audio files. When an item is clicked, the file is downloaded with the flutter_file_downloader plugin and stored locally, its local link is also retrieved and stored in a database. Once the download is complete, the playback page opens, receiving the local audio link as a parameter. So far so good; the link is retrieved ('/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.mp3') but unfortunately the file doesn't play. I use audioplayers. Permissions and all, it's fine.
I tried this code found here on stackoverflowbut it doesn't work.
var file = File(path);

   Uint8List bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();

   var buffer = bytes.buffer;

   var unit8 = buffer.asUint8List(32, bytes.lengthInBytes - 32);
   Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

   var tmpFile = "${dir.path}/tmp.mp3";
   var writeFile = File(tmpFile).writeAsBytesSync(unit8);
   var urlSource = DeviceFileSource(tmpFile);
   audioPlayer.play(urlSource); 

I also tried this, but still nothing.
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Create the audio player.
    player = AudioPlayer();

    // Set the release mode to keep the source after playback has completed.
    player.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.stop);

    // Start the player as soon as the app is displayed.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await player.setSource(DeviceFileSource(widget.item.audio!));
      await player.resume();
    });
    debugPrint("xxxLINK : ${widget.item.audio!}");
  }

